# What will be the range of $f(x)= \frac{12}{\sqrt{(15-2x-x^2)}}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Here's my try:
Since the denominator involves a square root so I solved the following inequality:
$15-2x-x^2>0$
which gives a solution set of $x=(-5,3)$. This is the domain of $f(x)$.
However since it is an open interval, I am unable to find the exact range of $f(x)$. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Then what will be the range of this function?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar But that is the domain of this function i.e x can take the values between -5 and 3.
I need the range, i.e the values f(x) can take.

Comment: Do you know how to find local minimums? If so, since you know the function blows up to infinity at -5 and 3, if you find the minimum of the function of the interval (-5,3), then your range is [minimum, infinity). Note: the minimum is included in the interval (unless it blows up to negative infinity somewhere, but in this case, it doesn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be first

$$15-2x-x^2=-(x^2+2x-15)=-(x+5)(x-3)>0\iff -5<x<3$$

Since $\;f(x)>0\;$ for all $\;x\in (-5,3)\;$ , we take $\;0<w\in\Bbb R\;$ , and

$$\frac{12}{\sqrt{15-2x-x^2}}=w\iff 144=15w^2-2w^2x-w^2x^2\iff$$

$$w^2x^2+2w^2x+144-15w^2=0$$

The discriminant of this quadratic must be nonnegative

$$b^2-4ac=4w^4-4w^2(144-15w^2)\ge 0\iff 16w^4-144w^2=16w^2(w^2-9)\ge 0\iff$$

$$w\le -3\;\;\text{or}\;\;w\ge 3$$

Comment: Indeed. I plotted it on an online grapher and yes the range is f(x)>= 3 going to positive infinity on both sides as the graph shows. (It can't be negative though!) Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it can't be negative as written there. Well deduced.+1

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that $15-2x-x^2$ is biggest at $x=-1$.